# SQL Aggregate function that shows if there is an homogeneous value in a group

Tags: ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am working in Access 2016 and I was wondering if there is an aggregate function which gives me a value, but only if the value is the same for the rows in the group, otherwise null.

For example, I have a list of bills and every bill has items. (Just a simplified example)

```
Table BILLS
- ID int
- NAME varchar(100)
- ...

Table ITEMS
- ID int
- FK_BILL_ID int
- PRICE currency
- PAID bool
- ...
```

My query is like:

```
select b.NAME as Name, sum(i.PRICE) as PriceSum, ????(i.PAID) as PayStatus
from BILLS b
left join ITEMS i on i.FK_BILL_ID = b.ID
group by b.ID, b.NAME
```

What I want to achieve:

```
Name   | PriceSum | PayStatus
-------+----------+-------------
Bill A |    19,99 | true
Bill B |    12,34 | false
Bill C |     9,99 | null
Bill D |    99,99 | null
```

- The field PayStatus should be true if all items are paid (PAID=true)
- The field PayStatus should be false if all items are not paid (PAID=false)
- Otherways, PayStatus should be null (if there are no items, or if only a part of the items were paid)

Answer (score 0):

Given that MS Access boolean field stores True as -1 and False as 0, we can write the query as shown below

```
SELECT b.BillNAME as BillName,
SUM(i.PRICE) AS PriceSum, IIF(SUM(PAID) =0, "FALSE", IIF( count(*)*-1 
=sum(PAID), "TRUE", "NULL")) as PayStatus
FROM BILLS b
left join ITEMS i on i.FK_BILL_ID = b.ID
GROUP BY BillName;
```

Please note that as Name is reserved word in MS Access, I have changed the field name to BillName.

Answer (score 0):

Is Paid field a Yes/No type?
Try an Expression in the aggregate query like:

`PayStatus: Switch(Count(*)=Abs(Sum([Paid])),"True", Sum([Paid])=0,"False", True,Null)`

Name is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names.

And I was composing when Alok answered. Great minds .... Although just multiplying by -1 probably better than calling Abs() function.